# How Can I refresh the specific lightning component after an update to the record

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

How Can I refresh the entire lightning page or a specific lightning component after an update to the record.

Answer (score 0):

You can use standard JS way -

```
window.location.reload()
```

or the lightning way -

```
$A.get('e.force:refreshView').fire();
```